# default(DateTime) / DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString()) has strange behavior in C# (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)

Tags: c#

`default(DateTime)` and `DateTime.Parse` has strange behavior. For input value of "12/31/9999" sometimes it returns correct value i.e. "12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM" but sometimes throws exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". This happens only on prod servers. Culture info on prod servers is en-US.

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(object obj)
{
    DateTime value = default(DateTime);            
    if (obj != null && !obj.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
    {                
        value = DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString());
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("value returned: " + value);
    return value;
}
```

Tried below to declare the variable. Sometimes it assigns "12/31/1950 12:00:00 AM", sometimes "31/12/1950 12:00:00 AM" to value1. Strange.

```
DateTime value1 = DateTime.ParseExact("12/31/1950", "MM/dd/yyyy", new     System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
value1 = DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString().Trim());` //Sometimes work, sometimes throws exception     string not valid datetime.
```

Any idea how to identify the root cause and fix this problem?

Comment: It does indeed sound like there's a different culture setting somewhere.  Or perhaps an explicit culture use somewhere which is different from the server's default.  *"Sometimes it assigns "12/31/1950 12:00:00 AM", sometimes "31/12/1950 12:00:00 AM" to value1."* - This statement sounds a bit misguided.  Those are **string** values.  Is the **DateTime** value the same between the two?  Where/how are those string values being observed?  Maybe a different culture or format is being used when **formatting** these values somewhere else?

Comment: It's unclear how you expect `default(DateTime)` to be relevant here - or indeed what the value of `obj` is when the code fails. (I'd strongly encourage to log the value of `obj.ToString()` before parsing it, and only call `ToString` once.)

Comment: Also use `DateTime.TryParse` instead of `DateTime.Parse` and log `obj` if it returns `false`

Comment: Regarding above 3 comments -
1) When added code in try catch block got info in catch block -
value in exception: 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM
exeption.Message: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
obj.ToString().Trim() in exception12/31/9999
CurrentCulture in exception: en-US
CurrentUICulture in exception: en-US
CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in exception: en-US

2) value of input parameter obj is "12/31/9999"
3) When used TryParse same behavior. Only difference is application does not throw the exception
input parameter value : 12/31/9999
returned value: 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: `MM/dd/yyyy` is a terrible date format. Having this as an OS default means that `dd/MM/yyyy` is also difficult to use. `yyyy-MM-dd` is the only format I would expect to work reliably without an explicit culture or `ParseExact` format string. Otherwise the behaviour of your program will change based on the user / environment settings. The question then is if you want your program to change based on the user / environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested parse method that should cover most possible date/time formats using [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0), including white spaces in the string.

```
static DateTime ParseDateTime(string dateString)
{
    string[] formats = 
        { "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
          "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
          "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
          "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
          "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
          "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
          "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
          "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss",
          "MM/dd/yyyy", 
          "M/d/yyyy" 
        };

    DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces;

    DateTime dateTime;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, null, styles, out dateTime))
    {
        return dateTime;
    }
    else
    {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```